# Specman UVM: How update a value of a register when the value was written to another register?

Tags: specman, uvm, e

(in my verification environment we use `vr_ad` package.). I try to implement the next:
When data is written to one of the registers (`timer_load`), another register (`timer_bgload`) should be updated with the same data.

I've found the next **example in UVM User Guide**:

```
// Attaching the target register file to the broadcasted register
extend ex_c_bus_env {
    post_generate() is also {
        xcore_regs.vr_ad_rx_data.attach(xbus_regs);
    };
};
// Implement the broadcast:
// When writing to register VR_AD_RX_DATA in XCORE vr_ad_reg_file,
// propagate the value to the VR_AD_XBUS_DATA register in ACTIVE_XBUS.
extend ACTIVE_XBUS vr_ad_reg_file {
    indirect_access( direction : vr_ad_rw_t, ad_item : vr_ad_base) is {
        if ad_item is a VR_AD_RX_DATA vr_ad_reg (d) {
            vr_ad_xbus_data.write_reg_val(d.get_cur_value());
        };
    };
};
```

**My registers:**

```
reg_def TIMER_LOAD_0 TIMER 20'h00010 {
    reg_fld timer_load : uint (bits : 32) : RW : 0xffff;
};


reg_def TIMER_BGLOAD_0 TIMER 20'h00014 {
    reg_fld timer_bgload : uint (bits : 32) : RW : 0xffff;
};


reg_def TIMER_BGLOAD_1 TIMER 20'h00028 { 
    reg_fld timer_bgload : uint (bits : 32) : RW : 0xffff;
    //another reg with the same instance name
};
```

**My code** for updating the `timer_bgload` register after a data was written to `tiemr_load`:

```
extend TIMER vr_ad_reg_file {
    indirect_access( direction : vr_ad_rw_t, ad_item : vr_ad_base) is {
        if ad_item is a TIMER_LOAD_0 vr_ad_reg (d) {
            timer_bgload.write_reg_val(d.get_cur_value());
        };
    };
};

unit timer_env_u like any_env {
    post_generate() is also {
        timer_regs.timer_load_0.attach(timer_regs.timer_bgload_0.timer_bgload);
    };  
};
```

I get a **compilation error**:

```
*** Error: No such variable 'timer_bgload'
                at line 17 in @timer_reg_db
            timer_bgload.write_reg_val(d.get_cur_value());
```

I really appreciate any help.

Comment: `timer_bgload` exists only at `TIMER_BGLOAD_0` and `TIMER_BGLOAD_1` (and they are not the same field!) you cannot access them from a `TIMER vr_ad_reg_file`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can attach the `timer_load` register to the `timer_bgload` register directly and implement `indirect_access(...)` there:

```
// attach the regs
extend TIMER vr_ad_reg_file {
  post_generate() is also {
    timer_load_0.attach(timer_bgload_0);
  }; 
};

// implement indirect_access()
extend TIMER_BGLOAD_0 vr_ad_reg {
  indirect_access(direction : vr_ad_rw_t, ad_item : vr_ad_base) is {
    if direction == WRITE and ad_item is a TIMER_LOAD_0 vr_ad_reg (d) {
      write_reg_val(d.get_cur_value());
    };
  };
};
```

I don't know why the Cadence example took the long route of attaching the register file to the indirect register.

Also, if you have more than one TIMER_LOAD/BGLOAD registers (seems like you may have 2), then the best thing to do is define the types first:

```
// define register types without instantiation in reg_file
reg_def TIMER_LOAD {
  reg_fld timer_load : uint (bits : 32) : RW : 0xffff;
};

reg_def TIMER_BGLOAD {
  reg_fld timer_bgload : uint (bits : 32) : RW : 0xffff;
};
```

After you define the types, you instantiate them in the register file manually as many times as you need to. Have a look in the manual, there is an example showing you exactly how to do it.

This means that it's enough to implement the `indirect_access(...)` method in the `TIMER_BGLOAD` subtype (only once) as opposed to two times (for `TIMER_BGLOAD_0` and `TIMER_BGLOAD_1`).

Answer (score 1):

I'd implement it with `post_access`, something like that:

```
extend TIMER_LOAD_0 TIMER vr_ad_reg {
    post_access(operation : vr_ad_rw_t) is {
        if operation == WRITE {
            var rgf := get_access_path()[0].as_a(TIMER vr_ad_reg_file);
            rgf.timer_bgload_0.timer_bgload = timer_load;
        };
    };
};
```

Pay attention, that it might not work on first hit. If it's not, I'd build it gradually, starting with 'empty' code like this:

```
extend TIMER_LOAD_0 TIMER vr_ad_reg {
    post_access(operation : vr_ad_rw_t) is {
        print me, operation;
    };
};
```

And putting a breakpoint in the `print` statement, opening a data browser, looking what are the exact names of the fields we got there, try to access them from Specman CLI - and when it works - code it back.

Comment: This is the way I used to do it too *with `post_access(...)`, but `indirect_access(...)` was designed specifically for this kind of thing.